# Puff pastry chocolate tart?

Tags: chocolate, puff-pastry

I've got some remaining puff pastry left over (1 sheet, store bought, frozen).

I have seen recipes online for puff pastry chocolate tarts, like here https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/76952/rich-chocolate-tart/

However, I don't have heavy cream now  so I plan on using the chocolate filling mixture from this recipe https://tasty.co/recipe/silkiest-chocolate-tart . But the recipe I just linked to above wants me to pour the mixture into the pre baked 'dough' and bake it further.

But, the recipe that I first linked to is for puff pastry and I don't think you can bake it twice?

Sorry if I sound confusing. I just want to know if it would be fine if, I would just bake the puff pastry for a little in the oven, then pour the mixture (from second recipe) into the thing then bake it further?  Or does anyone have any suggestions (or any other recipes for a puff pastry chocolate tart sort of thing, that doesn't need cream?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you can make the chocolate pudding in a saucepan (using a chocolate pudding mix), bake the puff pastry by itself in the oven for a few minutes and then spoon the pudding in to the puff pastry to make a delicious chocolate tart.

By the way, you can also do the same with fruit, such as apples, cherries, blueberries. You can either make a homemade fruit filling or buy canned fruit filling.
Good luck!

Comment: So I'd then just let the tart cool (let the mix cool) or eat it immediately?

Comment: @Magic_Whizz let the pudding cool and set in a fridge.

Answer (score 3):

Something with a pudding consistency is likely to be too wet/sloppy for puff pastry, even if you bake it separately.  It really does better with sort of dry ingredients.  Could you at least protect the puff pastry with say a layer of slivered nuts or something like that?

Is it really impossible for you to get the heavy cream called for?  And yes, baking puff pastry twice isn't likely to give good results, the puff will depart, the texture will be lost.